# Ruby on Rails 4.2 - jQuery and JSON to update progress bars

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

*Updated 12/15 from comments.

I am still stuck. Please TL:DR by scrolling down for the code.

I have a dice roller web application I am completing for a project. My mentor has <strike>demanded</strike> requested progress bars indicating the status of a run. A 'run' is defined as a collection of 'rolls', which contains one or more 'di(c)e', which contains one or more 'results' - the randomized number between 1 and the number of sides per die the user has chosen.

You can probably get an idea for what the schema of the back-end DB looks like.

The progress bars - just two - would track which roll is currently being worked, and how many dice have been rolled compared to how many will be in the most recent job submitted by the user.

These jobs are asynchronous using ActiveJob and SuckerPunch. It creates a job that performs all of the calculations and data writes. Problem is, I can't seem to get the data out of the job via AJAX in real time. My references to current Rails variables in my java pull null or undefined errors, and any attempts to place "respond_to" blocks within my job fail worse than I did at first-year college algebra.

Here is pertinent code.

runs_controller.rb (create method)

```
def create

@job = RollDiceJob.perform_later(run_params)
sleep(1)

respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

roll_dice_job.rb

```
  class RollDiceJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :low_priority

  def perform(run_params)
    # Do something later

    # Create the new run record.
    @run = Run.create(run_params)
    # apply the job_id to the job_id field of the run
    @run.job_id = self.job_id
    @run.save

    # Assign local variables for use in the job.
    roll_count = @run.roll_count.to_i # Integer value of roll_count field
    die_count = @run.die_count.to_i # ^^
    die_sides = @run.die_sides.to_i # ^^

    @natural = 0
    @total = 0

    # set counters for iterating through rolls and dice.
    i = 0


    # Start roll iterations

    while i < roll_count do
      #update the current roll field in the run table
      @run.current_roll = i+1
      @run.save

      # Set roll env variable to create a new Roll record passing the new roll_number as value of 'i' with each
      # iteration

      @roll = Roll.create(:run_id => @run.id, :roll_number => i+1)

      # increment to the next roll


      d = 0

      # start result iterations

      while d < die_count do
        #update the current die field in the run table
        @run.current_dice = d+1
        @run.save

        # Generate the random number.
        output = rand(1..die_sides)

        if output == die_sides
          @natural +=1
        end

        # Set results env variable to create a new Result record passing the die_number as the value of current
        # iteration 'd' and the output to the value of the array at 'd'

        @result = Result.create(:roll_id => @roll.id, :die_number => d+1, :output => output)

        @total += output

        d += 1

      end

      i += 1

    end

  end

end
```

create.js.erb

```
var max_roll = parseInt('<%= Run.get_roll_count(@job.job_id) %>', 10);
var max_dice = parseInt('<%= Run.get_die_count(@job.job_id) %>', 10);

$('#test').text('test: ' + max_roll + ' ' + max_dice)

if ($('#die_count').val() != '' && $('#roll_count').val() != '') {
  $('#notify').fadeOut('fast', function () {
    $('#submit_success_header').text('Run <%= Run.get_run_submitted(@job.job_id) %> submitted successfully.');
  });

  // $('#roll').attr('aria-valuemax', max_roll)
  // $('#dice').attr('aria-valuemax', max_dice)

  $('#notify').fadeIn();

  $('#die_count').val('');
  $('#roll_count').val('');

} else {
  alert("Please enter a value!")
  if ($('#die_count').val() != '') {
    $('#roll_count').focus();
  } else {
    $('#die_count').focus();
  }
}

$('#notify').html('<%= j render 'runs/submit' %>')
```

runs_submit.html.erb

```
<h3 id="submit_success_header"></h3>
<span id="test"></span>
<script>
  var roll_int = setInterval(function() {
    var current_roll = parseInt('<%= Run.get_current_roll(@job.job_id) %>', 10);
    var roll_dec = current_roll / max_roll;
    var roll_per = roll_dec * 100;
    $('#roll').attr({
    'aria-valuenow': current_roll,
    style: 'width:' + roll_per + '%'
  });
    $('#roll_progress_label').text(current_roll + '/' + max_roll);

    if (current_roll == max_roll) {
      clearInterval(roll_int)
    }
  }, 100);

  var dice_int = setInterval(function()  {
    var current_dice = parseInt('<%= Run.get_current_dice(@job.job_id) %>', 10);
    var dice_per = (current_dice / max_dice) * 100;
    $('#dice').attr({
      'aria-valuenow': current_dice,
      style: 'width:' + dice_per + '%'
    });

    $('#dice_progress_label').text(current_dice + '/' + max_dice);

    if (current_dice == max_dice) {
      clearInterval(dice_int)
    }
  }, 100);
</script>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="roll" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" data-roll_count="" aria-valuenow="70"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="" style="width:100%">
    <span id="roll_progress_label"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div id="dice" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span id="dice_progress_label"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out why that ERB that calls the model methods aren't reading per the interval. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Hey i thing you have to store current progress in database. if your job queue is in database then just add one more column there and update your progress. and create one method that read current progress from db n show on progress bar using AJAX. for that you have needed your job id. for more help refer https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job

Comment: I've seen that before and couldn't make the connection. I will try and update with results, and will mark as solution if applicable. Thanks, Vishal!

Comment: Ok, I applied the concept that you mentioned. I think. I created new columns in my run table for "Current Roll", "Job Id" and "Current Dice" that updates along with the values on corresponding tables inside the job that is creating the info, but I'm running into another quirk. My 'create' method Creates the job, which job applies the job_id within it, and grabs the run associated with the job ID. If I don't sleep it for 1 second, it doesn't find the record. It's a clunky delay. I'd like it to be instantaneous. Brings me back to the original question. Thoughts?

Comment: you have needed to call AJAx request for grabbing current status from that table.

Comment: Just updated the post to include my code, and I'm still stuck. I have AJAX with the 'remote: true' set up in my form, with the controller responding to .js. I have my create.js.erb doing some stuff, then rendering the partial, which houses the "setInterval" call and the ERB that should make a database read every tenth of a second. It's not. Only grabs the current one at load time. What AJAX am I missing? What would JSON do for me that this doesn't?